# Leased Line bandwidth distribution among users

Tags: bandwidth, bandwidth-control

Say that i purchase a 4 Mb leased line (Radio wave), and also i have around 50-75 users using the connection.

What will the speed will each user get ? Will the 4MB be divided among all 75 users or will all users receive the same speed throughout the day ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be entirely dependent on what everyone was doing at any given moment. The minimum bandwidth everyone could get would be 1/75th of the 4Mb (everyone streaming videos for example). The maximum could be 4Mb, with only one person using the line.

Answer (score 4):

> Will the 4MB be divided among all 75 users or will all users receive
>   the same speed throughout the day

You buy one pizza. YOu have 4 guests. Will every guest get a complete pizza?

Com on, that is common sense. NATURALLY the limited resource (4Mbit bandwidth) will be distributed among the users that actually use it (which is less than 50-75 - not everyone will have the same demands at exactly the same moment).

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually it depends on the queue management on each end. If it is a FIFO queue, in case you have eg a big FTP transfer between the two sites, it will consume the whole bandwidth while connections to Internet will suffer and telnet will seem unresponsive.

Normally you would put a router on each end, shape the output interface of the router (which probably is ethernet) to 4Mbps, configure a QoS policy and apply fair-queueing, random-detect. You could also prioritize or reserve bandwidth for some applications.